# Themes in Android?

Tags: android, themes

I have an idea to create Themes for Android Mobile. But I have no knowledge of how to do this. I would need to know about the following things:

- What is the file format of a theme for Android?
- What kind of things I want to handle to change the themes (i.e background, directory window, wallpaper, icon selector style, etc.)
- How to start to learn about this
- Sites and tutorials for beginners
- Sample applications and code

If you passed by information about anything above, please share with me. It would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: unless you are customizing OS for a device themes perOS is not possible..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would start with Google's page on Styles and Themes.  Many of your questions are answered there.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Here's a simple tutorial:

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=309

**EDIT:**

If you are talking about themes for the phone instead of the app, you can create themes for specific home screen replacements such as [aHome](http://www.mappn.com/soft.php?id=2).  I'm sure if you look around their site you can see how to create a theme for their app.

There are also sites like [Android Themes](http://android-themes.net/), but they require that you have rooted your phone and have installed a custom ROM such as those by Cyanogen.

Perhaps you could also write your own custom home screen.

Comment: i am not asking about My Application theme buddy. i need about mobile themes.