# Add different themes to the android application

Tags: android, themes

i want to add themes to my android application. In the application, user will have options to changes theme of the application. Just like [OIShopping List appplication](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/19). Please help how do i implement this kind of structure to my application.

Any help, tutorials, guidance are highly appreciated.

thanks..

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613101/themes-in-android

Comment: No, you are asking about mobile device themes, here i am just talking about themes for a single android app. Please view the OI Shopping list application. They are using different themes for their app. So please dont get confused with mobile device themes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method
`setTheme()` within an onClickListener, and inbetween the parenthesis put the theme.