# Get background images from an installed themes android

Tags: android, themes

I am having some themes in my device.How can i get the icons,background images of those themes in my application? please help me guys

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean like HandsetSMS or other applications in which you can download new themes from the market and install them to skin your app, then check out [this](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/348) link. It is [OpenIntents](http://www.openintents.org/en/), and it is a bunch of different applications (open-source) that have skinning capabilities. Take a look at OINotepad and [check out the source](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/checkout) to see how it works.

Good luck and I hope this helped!

EDIT: I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921038/add-different-themes-to-the-android-application) isn't answered yet, but you should keep checking up on it to see if it gets any answers because I *think* it's the same question as yours.