# Switching application-wide theme programmatically?

Tags: android, themes, android-theme

I'm attempting to get a user-chosen theme and feel like I'm frustratingly close. Defining the theme in `AndroidManifest.xml` works as it should, but (as best I can tell) can't change based on app preferences:

```
<application 
    android:theme="@style/theme_sunshine" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Alternatively, setting it dynamically in each activity also works:

```
someChosenTheme = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("themePreference", "theme_twilight");
setTheme(someOtherChosenTheme);
```

But that seems messy, and I'd rather set the theme for the entire app in one place. My first thought was to grab the application context as soon as my main activity launches and do it there:

```
getApplicationContext().setTheme(R.style.theme_dummy);
```

As best I can tell, [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setTheme%28int%29) ought to do the trick, but in fact it's not doing anything - the entire app has the default Android style. Is the above valid, and if so, might I be doing something else dumb?

I'm working in API level 3 if that matters. Prods in the right direction greatly appreciated!

[Related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475207/multi-theme-support-in-android-app)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Create a base activity for your app and override `onCreate` to set the theme. Derive all your other activities from this base activity.

Also check this tutorial:

http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html

Comment: This is essentially what I'm doing. It's still not ideal, since there's no multiple inheritance, e.g. for a custom ListActivity, but the inconvenience is minor. Very helpful tutorial, even though I've already read it :)

Comment: I acutally have a BaseListActivity and a Base(Generic)Activity in every app I do. The BaseListActivity has common handling of CRUD (read, add, edit, delete) built in, so it is very easy to create a new list activity and just override a few methods. Of course, if I add a MapActivity or TabActivity, I'd have to create a BaseXActivity for them as well. Sometimes multi inheritance is just better :)

Comment: So adding setTheme for each activity, before "setContentView" is called is really the correct solution? isn't there a single system wide solution? also, what happens with all of the activities that are already alive?

Comment: For active activities just call recreate() whenever the theme changes. The flicker is ugly but we'll have to live with it.

Comment: Great tutorial link that helps me answer an unrelated question I got recently. "Where are attributes like ?actionBarSize defined and how they work" :)

Comment: The link does work but the source code inside does not as it gives a Dropbox error. The main question is therefore not answered anywhere else in the article to show how to programmatically change a theme.

Answer (score 5):

There may be a good solution to this, but I couldn't find one, so I ended up making a little static helper method in a helper class that takes an Activity and basically performs those two lines you wrote. Sure, it's not perfect, but just adding one short line of code to every `onCreate()` method in my app was tolerable.