# I want my users to be able to switch from a dark and light theme for my entire app

Tags: android, themes

I have my dark and light styles setup.

I want the user to be able to change from light/dark theme in my settings activity.

I have the dialog that pops up and lets choose light or dark.

I have read that this cannot be done dynamically and that fine. I dont mind the app restarting for changes to apply.

I have seen other apps like falcon pro that allow this. i have it setup just like that. in falcon pro it asks if you want to restart app now or later.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` has a `setTheme` method. You have to call it at any activity, or better create a BaseActivity which does that and inherited any of your Activities by that BaseActivity

[Switching application-wide theme programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663752/switching-application-wide-theme-programmatically)

Comment: so my main activity starts then the user can click settings to go to my settings activity. That is where they can change the light/dark theme. 

i read this from the link you provided
`To set the theme dynamically at runtime, call setTheme() in your activity's onCreate() method, before calling setContentView().  To change the theme, you simply need to restart your activity.`


but how am i supposed to implement that to the main activity?