# Change theme in Android app

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I want dynamically change the theme of my app with buttons, so I implemented this:

```
 sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("VALUES",MODE_PRIVATE);
    int theme = sharedPreferences.getInt("THEME",2);

    switch (theme){
        case 1: setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            break;
        case 2: setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_AppBarOverlay);
            break;
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutotial);
```

And this is the code of the buttons:

```
        tb1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    tb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("THEME",1).apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(tutotial.this, tutotial.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

tb2 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    tb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("THEME",2).apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(tutotial.this, tutotial.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(tutotial.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);

        }
    });
```

The problem is that code just changes the theme of the activity associated and it does not make the change theme in all the app.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open source podcast player called AntennaPod on github](https://github.com/AntennaPod/AntennaPod). It contains example code that does this.

The way they do it is to call `ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(int)` at the beginning of each `Activity.onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(UserPreferences.getTheme());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ......
}
```

This could be done in each activity, or by creating a base activity that does this for you on each subclass.

---

On closer reading of your question, **this is exactly what you are doing**. So I would say you are on the right track.

---

It also seems this has been asked before:

- [Switching application-wide theme programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663752/switching-application-wide-theme-programmatically)
- [Android - Change app Theme on onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301554/android-change-app-theme-on-onclick?lq=1)
- [I want my users to be able to switch from a dark and light theme for my entire app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581221/i-want-my-users-to-be-able-to-switch-from-a-dark-and-light-theme-for-my-entire-a?lq=1)

All offering the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a theme to any activity by including `android:theme` inside `activity` inside manifest file.

For example:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
<activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

And if you want to set theme programatically then use `setTheme()` before calling `setContentView()` and `super.onCreate()` method inside `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I want to set theme programatically and i did that you told me. The poroblem is the code i implemented just set the theme of one activiy and i want to set all the activities. I have two themes in styles.xml, one per each button

Comment: that's excatly what i said. in each <activity> tag put the theme that you want, or another solution is to set your theme before setContentView() in each of your activities

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by implementing various themes and on click of button change the themes accordingly, refer this [change theme programatically](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/changing-your-android-apps-theme-dynamically.html) for assistance.