# Which method in AOSP parses res/values/styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I'd like to know which class/method parses the `styles.xml` file in Android apps' resource folder.

I need to set the attribute `windowIsTranslucent` to `true` for several applications which source code I don't have.

I thought I could hook into the method that parses the `styles.xml` file and "force" the value of the attribute, using the [Xposed framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053).

Comment: I barely know the Framework but overriding Activity#onCreate *could* be a suitable entrypoint to set that property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please suggest how I could achieve that ? I have already used Xposed to hook on `Activity#onCreate` then used `getWindow().getContext().setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);` but the transparency was applied only to the activity, not the "external zone" on the screen, which made me think that `setTheme()` does actually not have the same effect as `styles.xml`

Comment: Is the external zone the status bar? That can only be made translucent on kitkat. Unless you hook into the event loop itself and somehow change it's color from there. Try reading this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663752/switching-application-wide-theme-programmatically

Comment: No. I just want to make some apps have a [floating window](http://cases.azoft.com/android-tutorial-floating-activity/). It is simple to  hook on `Activity#onAttachedToWindow()` (using Xposed) to resize/move the activities, but I couldn't find how to alter the value of `windowIsTranslucent` to make the "external zone" transparent and allow for touch events to go through.

Comment: Oh, you mean something like Paranoid's HALO? I believe it has been implemented already as an Xposed Module. In any case, i believe XDA Developers' forums would be a better place to ask this question