# How to set App Theme programatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Now I am going on with app theme transparency that is i have one class.

I have two button options if user click one button it should load app theme and for other one transparency should load.

So i decided to show transparency theme progrmatically for that set parent layout id in class and tried to set the theme there but i can't able to set.

Reffered many set but no use if some have idea about this please help me friends.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switching application-wide theme programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663752/switching-application-wide-theme-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `setTheme(..)` before calling `setContentView(...)` and `super.oncreate()`

Answer (score 1):

Go in manifest file:

**First set theme for all application:**

```
    <application
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" > <!--Your theme-->
      ...
```

**You can set Theme for every activity**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.FirsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_firsactivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"> <!--Your theme for this activity-->
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_secondactivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"> <!--Your theme for this activity-->
    </activity>
```

**And go to activity.xml and on top bar ,set same theme like in manifest**

Comment: Now I am going on with app theme transparency that is i have one class.

I have two button options if user click one button it should load app theme and for other one transparency should load.

Comment: Create two themes in style, and in your java.class write samthing like that: if(true){setTheme( android.R.style.ThemeFirst ); } else { setTheme( android.R.style.ThemeSecond ); }