# Change Background color of app, depending on list item clicked

Tags: android, colors, onclick

I have a ListView with color names (array of strings stored in separate xml). How do I change background of my application depending on which color in the list I clicked? I have a function that displays a toast message depending on Item clicked but I don't know how to transform it into background color changing function.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switching application-wide theme programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663752/switching-application-wide-theme-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the OnItemClickListener you can change the color depending on the Text of the ListView Item.

To solve this problem, you just need to use an if-else checking the value of the TextView and then changing the color. I am assuming that you don't have color resources, so I use the ARGB values.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Save the color name into a variable
        String colorName=((TextView) view).getText().toString();

        //Default is color White
        int color=Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255);

        //Check the color name
        if(colorName.equals("black"))
        {
           color=Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (colorName.equals("red"))
        {
            color=Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0);
        }
        //...and so on with other colors

        //Find the background view using the layout id. Then you will be able to change the background with the color
        findViewById(R.id.id_of_the_layout).setBackgroundColor(color);

    }
});
```

Comment: I actually have two arrays, one with names of colors and other with their hex value. How do I put them both together?

Comment: If they are stored in the same order (for instance, Array1=[Black,Red...] and Array2=["#000000","#FF0000"...] then you need to do this: color=Color.parseColor(Array2[position]), so using this way even you won't need the if-else

Answer (score 0):

Your activity has a layout.

Give it a name ( here is one named outer container. )

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/outer_container"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

Do a findViewById on it and then set the color on the view.

```
     View view = findViewById( R.id.outer_container );
     view.setBackground or view.setBackgroundColor
```

Comment: The problem for me is to get value from ListView and then setting background color equal to this value

Answer (score 0):

ListViews has an adapter, a customized one or a standard like `ArrayAdapter`. Something like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

You can also create a custom adapter to store complex objects extending `BaseAdapter`. In your case, it might be enough with String. You can store hexadecimal codes for each different item in the list.

To get items from the adapter use `getItem(int position)` method.

```
String colorCode = itemsAdapter.getItem(position);
```

So, in your itemClickListener:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String colorCode = itemsAdapter.getItem(position);
        setBackgroundColor(colorCode);
    }
});
```

Your set backgroundColor method will use a reference to the parent container that you must store at startup.

```
View parentContainer;

...
// at onCreate
parentContainer = findViewById(R.id.container_id);
...

void setBackgroundColor(String colorCode) {
    int color = Color.parseColor(colorCode);
    parentContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```