# How to apply colors programmatically to app theme?

Tags: android, colors, themes

I have some problem about apply colors to my app. 
I want to achieve to get some json from the web, like this:

```
{
   "colorPrimary": "#45a02c",
   "colorAccent": "#a02c2c",
   "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
}
```

and store it in a object like ThemeColor, i created. Parsing the json to object is no problem, but now i want to create a method in my ThemeColor class,  that will apply the colors of the object to my app, so that my toolbar will colored in this primary color or i can use it with `?attr/colorPrimary` .

Is that possible?
And what would be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to \_really\_ programmatically change primary and accent color in Android Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your custom theme inside `style.xml` and use that inside your activity

style.xml

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/your_custom_color</item>
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/your_custom_color_2</item>
     <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/your_custom_colot_3</item>
</style>
```

And use that theme inside your activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.CustomTheme); //here your custom theme
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
}
```

Comment: But on this way, i cant change colors to my json colors, right? I mean, the json colors will change at runtime...

Comment: Right, you can't change your `color.xml` using above way.

Comment: that's because, it's immutable

Comment: You may look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482848/how-to-change-current-theme-at-runtime-in-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663752/switching-application-wide-theme-programmatically)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987678/programmatically-change-the-value-of-a-color-resource-obtained-from-api-response) is the solution that may you looking for.

Comment: Ok, thank you all. @Mehul Solanki thats not the answer i was looking for, but you are right!