# How to create a custom theme and use it in an Android application?

Tags: android, themes

How to create a custom themes and use it in the code?

In menu how to implement theme option and apply for the activity?

Comment: check my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613101/themes-in-android

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html) post. Probably this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 14):

There's a nice [Styles and Themes guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) on the android developers site. Basically what you need to do is

1. [Define a style](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles) (or inherit a built-in one). To define a style

> save an XML file in the `res/values/` directory of your project. The
>   name of the XML file is arbitrary, but it must use the `.xml` extension
>   and be saved in the `res/values/` folder.
>
> The root node of the XML file must be `<resources>`.
>
> For each style you want to create, add a  element to the file
>   with a name that uniquely identifies the style (this attribute is
>   required).

i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyGreenTheme" parent="Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">#11aa22</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

It's useful to name the resource file `themes.xml` so it's easier to recognize what those styles are used for.

2. [Apply](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyingStyles) the defined style to the activity or view that you want
   stylized. You can either

   - set the Activity/Application theme in the manifest file:

   `<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.MyGreenTheme"/>`

   - or set it dynamically - use the corresponding setter of the Activity class - [setTheme()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme(int)).

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) is perfect site which creates all the necessary files you need to make a custom UI. I used it personally a couple of weeks ago and it worked great for me.

I have no affiliation with this site but found it very interesting.
Hope this may help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Create Custome Views:

public class CustomTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

```
public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setCommonChanges(DefaultTheme.getInstance().textColor, true, context);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setDefaultValues(context, attrs);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setDefaultValues(context, attrs);
}

private void setDefaultValues(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);
    final int N = a.getIndexCount();
    int color = DefaultTheme.getInstance().textColor;
    boolean isCustomFont = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomTextView_isCustomFont, true);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {

        int colorIndex = a.getInteger(R.styleable.CustomTextView_tvBackground, 2);
        switch (colorIndex) {
            case 1:
                color = DefaultTheme.getInstance().headingTextColor;
                break;

            case 2:
                color = DefaultTheme.getInstance().textColor;
                break;

            case 3:
                color = DefaultTheme.getInstance().textHintColor;
                break;

            case 4:
                color = DesignUtils.getColorIdFromHexCode("#FFFFFF");
                break;

            case 5:
                color = DefaultTheme.getInstance().iconColor;
                break;
            case 6:
                color = DefaultTheme.getInstance().menuHeaderTextColor;
                break;
            case 7:
                color = DefaultTheme.getInstance().menuTextColor;
                break;
            case 8:
                color = DefaultTheme.getInstance().keyboardtextcolor;
                break;
            case 9:
                color = DesignUtils.getColorIdFromHexCode("#BEBEBE");
                break;
        }


    }
    a.recycle();

    setCommonChanges(color, isCustomFont, context);
}

private void setCommonChanges(int color, boolean isCustomFont, Context context) {
    if (isCustomFont) {
        Typeface typeface = DefaultTheme.getInstance().getTVFont(context);
        setTypeface(typeface, getTypeface().getStyle());
    }
    setTextColor(color);
}

public void updateTypeFace(int style){
    Typeface typeface = DefaultTheme.getInstance().getTVFont(getContext());
    setTypeface(typeface, style);
}
```