# How to create android themes

Tags: android

My client wants to create themes like this:
http://mappn.com/community/index.php?topic=42.0

I have no clue where to start. When I Googled it I just get themes for style/theme for application.

Can anyone suggest where to start learning customizing themes for android phones?

Please share if you find any opensource.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613101/themes-in-android

Answer (score 0):

The default Android home screen is not themeable, so you will either need to write your own replacement home screen, or write a theme for one of the [existing home screen replacements](http://www.androidtapp.com/tag/custom-android-home-screen/) that others have written and support their own custom themes. Not all are free, and not all support themes.

I don't know much about writing your own Android home screen, other than a home screen activity should respond to the `android.intent.category.HOME` category in its intent filter ([About intent filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs)).

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at framework-res.apk - most modding is done there.
Normaly you find it at /system/framework/framework-res.apk. 
You can open it with Winrar or 7-Zip and take a look at all the ressources in there.

For more just google it :)

edit:  [a starting link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=470268)